# Replacing variables in jQuery keeps using the prior value

Tags: jquery

I have the next input that shows "buy" value by default

```
    <input class="myVar" data-buy="50000" data-sell="80000" value="5000" />
    <button id="change">CHANGE PRICES</button>
    <button id="toggle">TOGGLE</button>
```

I click on "#change" in order to increase the amount of "buy" and "sell"

```
     $(document).on("click", #change", function(){
         $(".myVar").attr("data-buy",6000);
         $(".myVar").attr("data-sell",9000);
      
     });
```

Now if I toggle the value shown in "myVar" input restores to   the default values.

```
      $("#toggle").toggle(
     function(){
   
       $(".myVar").val($(".myVar").data("buy"));
       },
      function(){ 
      $(".myVar").val($(".myVar").data("sell"));
      }

      );
```

What am I doing wrong?

I know the variables need to be set on the DOM,

I tried

```
       $(document).on("click", ".change", function(){
         $(".myVar").attr("data-buy",6000);
         $(".myVar").attr("data-sell",9000);
                    $("#toggle").click()
      
     });
```

but it changes the behaviour but it still show the initial values.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, but the first issue I see is that "change" is an ID, not a class, so your selector should be `$(document).on("click", "#change", ...`.

Comment: it was just a typo. There is a problem posted

Comment: Next, I'm not sure what you are trying to do with `$("#toggle").toggle()`, but I am almost certain you are confused about what it does. `.toggle()` is for toggling an element(s) `display` property - ie., showing/hiding the element. See: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Yes I need to toggle the input value displayed.

Comment: In order to change the data- values back to what they were previously you will need a reference to those previous values.

Comment: how do I reference them?

Comment: I think you need to more clearly explain what you are trying to do. I am unable to make much sense of it.

Comment: The post is self explanatory. There are html tags, an input that shows a value. Once I click on "change prices" the data values updates to 6000 and 9000. Then when I click on "toggle" I want to display a toggling value of 6000 and 9000 in the input. The problem is that it shows 5000 and 8000 despite the data values are already updated to 6000 and 9000

Comment: I disagree that this is self-explanatory, but I am understanding that you want something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/59L8k2mz/

Comment: here there is a fiddle. It doesnt work if you first click on "toggle" and then in "change prices" http://jsfiddle.net/cfge2h7m/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code.

The first is really the only problem for you in your environment, I think.  [Using .data() is the correct way](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to access and manipulate data attributes, but I noticed that your code mixes using `.data()` and `.attr()` to access the same values, eg:

```
$(".myVar").attr("data-buy",6000);
```

and

```
$(".myVar").val($(".myVar").data("buy"));
```

Replacing the cases where you're using `.attr()` to instead consistently use `.data()` is all that is needed to get your code working as you describe (with old versions of jQuery, see next item).  Here's a working snippet using jQuery 1.8.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#change", function() {
  $(".myVar").data("buy", 6000);
  $(".myVar").data("sell", 9000);
});

$("#toggle").toggle(
  function() {
    $(".myVar").val($(".myVar").data("buy"));
  },
  function() {
    $(".myVar").val($(".myVar").data("sell"));
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<input class="myVar" data-buy="50000" data-sell="80000" value="5000" />
<button id="change">CHANGE PRICES</button>
<button id="toggle">TOGGLE</button>
```

The second problem relates to `.toggle()`.  In old versions of jQuery, there was a [`toggle()` event handler](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), but it was deprecated long ago ([in version 1.8, from 2012!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery#Release_history)).  Presumably you are using an ancient version of jQuery where this still works, but for security reasons alone you should probably upgrade.

In any version of jQuery less than 10 years old, [`.toggle()` will show or hide an element](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).  In your code that means the <kbd>toggle</kbd> button just disappears immediately on page load.  Here's a copy of the above snippet, changed only to use the current version of jQuery, which demonstrates that.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#change", function() {
  $(".myVar").data("buy", 6000);
  $(".myVar").data("sell", 9000);
});

$("#toggle").toggle(
  function() {
    $(".myVar").val($(".myVar").data("buy"));
  },
  function() {
    $(".myVar").val($(".myVar").data("sell"));
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="myVar" data-buy="50000" data-sell="80000" value="5000" />
<button id="change">CHANGE PRICES</button>
<button id="toggle">TOGGLE</button>
```

If and when you do upgrade jQuery, you'll need to update this code too.  All you really need is a click handler, AFAICT, to trigger display of one value or the other.  The catch is you need to track which one is currently displayed, so that you can show the other one when the button is clicked.  Maybe we can use another `data` attribute on the input to track which is currently being displayed, something like:

```
<input class="myVar" data-showing="buy" ...
```

Then when you click the <kbd>toggle</kbd> button you can check which is currently shown, load and show the other, and then update that attribute to save the current state.  Note we need an extra case to handle the initial state, when the displayed value is neither the buy value nor the sell value (I'm not sure if that is just a typo or actually required).

Here's an example:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#change", function () {
    $(".myVar").data("buy", 6000);
    $(".myVar").data("sell", 9000);
});

$("#toggle").on('click', function () {
    let val = '';
    let showing = $(this).data('showing');
    
    // Handle both buy case and initial case when displayed value is neither sell or buy value
    if (showing === 'buy' || showing === '') {
        val = $(".myVar").data("sell");
        showing = 'sell';
    } else {
        val = $(".myVar").data("buy");
        showing = 'buy';
    }
    
    $(".myVar").val(val);
    $(this).data('showing', showing);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<input class="myVar" data-showing="" data-buy="50000" data-sell="80000" value="5000" />
<button id="change">CHANGE PRICES</button>
<button id="toggle">TOGGLE</button>
```

Comment: Thank you man. I realized I needed to use data() instead of attr(), now it works well. Yes Im using a very old version of Jquery since it is very lightweight and it still do the job. Thank you, your answer is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `$(...).data` and use `$(...).attr("data-type",...)`

This is what I did.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // CHANGE PRICES click
  $("#change").click(function(){
    $(".myVar").attr("data-buy",6000);
         $(".myVar").attr("data-sell",9000);
  });
  
  // toggle click
  $("#toggle").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr("data-type") === 'buy'){
        $(".myVar").val($(".myVar").attr("data-buy"));
        $(this).attr("data-type",'sell');
    }else{
        $(".myVar").val($(".myVar").attr("data-sell"));
        $(this).attr("data-type",'buy');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="myVar" data-buy="50000" data-sell="80000" value="50000" />
    <button id="change">CHANGE PRICES</button>
    <button data-type="sell" id="toggle">TOGGLE</button>
```